# Machine learning using ReLu return NaN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to figure out this whole machine learning thing, so I was making some testing. I wanted to make it learn the sinus function (with a radian angle). The neural network is:

**1 Input (radian angle) / 2 hidden layer / 1 output (prediction of the sinus)**

For the squash activation I am using: **RELU** and it's important to note that when I was using the Logistic function instead of RELU the script was working.

So to do that, I've made a loop that start at 0 and finish at 180, and it will translate the number in radian (radian = loop_index*Math.PI/180) then it'll basically do the sinus of this radian angle and store the radian and the sinus result.

So my table look like this for an entry: {input:[RADIAN ANGLE], output:[sin(radian)]}

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
    radian = (i*(Math.PI / 180));
    train_table.push({input:[radian],output:[Math.sin(radian)]})
}
```

I use this table to train my Neural Network using **Cross Entropy** and a learning rate of 0.3 with 20000 iterations.

The problem is that it fail, when I try to predict anything it returns "NaN"

I am using the framework Synaptic (https://github.com/cazala/synaptic) and here is a JSfiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/my7xe9ks/2/

Comment: You would need to share the complete code, not just this part which seems quite irrelevant IMHO.

Comment: Adding the language tag might help. Is that javascript? Which library are you using? How are you calculating the cross-entropy?

Comment: I am using javascript using this framework: https://github.com/cazala/synaptic and here is a jsfiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/my7xe9ks/2/

Comment: When I change the learning rate to 0.03 it seems to do something, but the results are not really precise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A learning rate must be carefully tuned, this parameter matters a lot, specially when the gradients explode and you get a nan. When this happens, you have to reduce the learning rate, usually by a factor of 10.

In your specific case, the learning rate is too high, if you use 0.05 or 0.01 the network now trains and works properly.

Also another important detail is that you are using cross-entropy as a loss, this loss is used for classification, and you have a regression problem. You should prefer a mean squared error loss instead.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, is there any way of determining the learning rate or do I have to tune it manually and wait to get the perfect one ?

Comment: @Raphael It has to be tuned manually, but there are optimizers like Adagrad, ADAM and RMSProp that help by scaling the learning rate automatically during training.

Comment: when using the MSE (Mean Squared Error) as you suggested the results get completely wrong at a certain time. I've used a learning rate of 0.005 (and tried other learning rate but it was doing the same) here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/my7xe9ks/4/ do you have any idea of what could cause that ?

Comment: @Raphael I wouldn't say "completely wrong", this network is quite simple, you have to experiment other network architectures that might better fit this data. Training a neural network is a lot more than just putting data in and out.